# Git bash setup rejecting global/ local parameters, can't set up user account

Tags: git, bash

**OS: Win8.1  64bit; Git v 2.9.0**

Git bash 2.9.0 set up rejecting user name & email configuration error messages.

- Installed -> exe'd -> no welcome message just computer name and $prompt.
- In command, I typed in the code provided by our TA:  **config [--local | --global] user.email "my email@etc.com"**; rec'd error messages:: --global] user.email command not found
- Repeated for user.name "name" and rec'd these errors:: bash: -global] user.email command not found; error: key does not contain section [--local.  These were the instructions by the TA left on group discussions.
- I then tried to bracket global by itself (git config [--global] and rec'd a fatal error: not in git directory.
- I uninstalled the program and want to reinstall but am worried the new d/load will just pick up the old settings from the 1st instance of the program. 
  What do I need to do to set my git bash up? I have an assignment due in a couple of days. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> In command, I typed in the code provided by our TA: config [--local | --global] user.email "my email@etc.com"; rec'd error messages:: --global] user.email command not found

The notation `[--local | --global]` is an optional `OR` choice. `[-A|-B]` means you shall use `-A` or `-B` as parameters to call the program. So, you want to:

`$ git config --local user.email you@example.com`

or

`$ git config --global user.email you@example.com`

From `git help config`: (bold is mine)

> When reading, the values are read from the system, global and repository local configuration files by default, and options **--system, --global, --local** and --file  can be used
>          to tell the command to read from only that location (see the section called “FILES”).

- `--local` means repository only configuration.
- `--global` means all your git operations (user level)
- `--system` means system wide configuration (users defaults for those that has not set above levels)

Comment: Sorry JrBenito, I didn't see your answer until after I hit post.  Your answer is much better, thank you.

Comment: @KEll no need to be sorry, you found solution after all and this is the primary goal; we are sharing knowledge right? Furthermore, you can still accept one or another as answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

- There are no brackets around the local or global parameters.
- There are spaces between the defined parameters and arguments
- user.name is entered as:

  ```
  $ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  $ git config --local user.name "Your Name"
  ```
- user.email is entered as:

  ```
  $ git config --global user.email "Your email"
  $ git config --local user.email "Your email
  ```

To **verify** user name and user email:

```
$ git config --list
```